# Ionizing radiation and oxidation without oxidizing agents

Tags: redox, ions, oxidation-state, reduction-potential

My knowledge on this subject is a bit rusty, so excuse me if I'm asking the wrong question here. I was taking a look at my high school chemistry books from many years ago, and I noticed that *reduction* and *oxidation* reactions take part together; meaning that ***you can't have oxidation without an oxidizing agent***.

My question is, that if we have a source of radiation, that emits *alpha* particles, which attract electrons, or *beta* particles which repel them, or a source of powerful electromagnetic radiation like gamma radiation, that can knock electrons off of atoms, and we bombard some gas with radiation, *ionizing* it, then would it count as **oxidation without reduction**? What exactly is going on redox-wise? We would have positive ions, but no oxidizing agent, or would we?

Comment: We would, but not for long. Soon enough, the ions will find their electrons and recombine with them, so the net result chemistry-wise will be _"nothing but some heat"_. That is, unless we have alpha particles. With them, it is just plain redox reaction with well-defined oxidizing agent.

Comment: Ionisation is different thing then redox.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You mean, that He<sup>2+</sup> particles can attract those electrons themselves and get reduced? I'm thinking, because of the mass of alpha particles, they would send electrons flying, and not attract them into an orbit. How would it be a redox then?

Comment: @Mithoron They sure are different. Oxidation is loss of electrons. In case of my question, it is ionization with positive charge, and loss of electrons, and thus, oxidation.

Comment: When they would just kick electrons out, that would not be a redox, precisely for the reason explained in my first comment. When they finally will attract them into an orbit, it would.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh, you meant the ionized gas itself! I thought you meant that alpha particles could get reduced. That does make sense now. But still my question remains. Do we have an oxidation without instant reduction, and then a reduction of positively charged gas, without oxidation? I mean, that they aren't simultaneous, and the gas, which is being reduced is the one that got oxidized a brief moment before that.

Comment: Yes I meant exactly that: alpha particles can and will get reduced. That would be a typical redox reaction, when one party gets oxidized and the other reduced.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But I still don't quite understand. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think alpha particles cannot absorb electrons into orbit, due to high velocity. Not until they slow down, and then they eventually become neutral He. What I thought was happening was that electrons would be scattered towards moving alpha particles, but due to their mass being roughly 7200 times (I'm just guessing) smaller than that of alpha particles, they would stick around and get absorbed by the ionized gas again. Isn't it what's happening in reality?

Comment: Well, that's mostly right: when the alpha particles move fast, they will just kick electrons out. Before these electrons reunite with their native atoms, they might briefly get absorbed by some other atoms. Calling _that_ a redox would be somewhat of a stretch, as to me.

Comment: It's interesting that *beta* source Tc has been used as a corrosion *inhibitor*. "55 ppm of potassium pertechnetate... protects steel from corrosion, even if the temperature is raised to 250 °C (523 K)." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium Though this is a chemical effect, does *beta* emission have any effect?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It is an interesting phenomenon indeed. Electrical current can prevent corrosion, and to be exact, "oxidation", buy supplying electrons to a solid metal. Beta particles are nothing but negatively charged electrons. If you bombard a solid metal with beta, you are in fact supplying it with electrons. In gas state, however, things can be different, and you can ionize some gas with beta. But, you know, you're dealing with radioactive materials, and the amount of electrons depend on the half life of the matter, and it's mass. Electricity would be a much more efficient way.